# Is Javadoc the right way to tell a user of a security issue?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm trying to answer this question and I believe the Javadoc would solve the problem:

You have found that a method in one of your (otherwise excellent) classes has a security problem and you want to tell users that it is not a good idea to use the method anymore. How do you do this?

Comment: Make the method deprecate?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to **deprecate** the method.

[How and when to deprecate API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html)

> When you design an API, carefully consider whether it supersedes an
>   old API. If it does, and you wish to encourage developers (users of
>   the API) to migrate to the new API, then deprecate the old API. Valid
>   reasons to deprecate an API include:
>
> It is insecure, buggy, or highly inefficient

This will automatically get included in the Javadocs and will give a clear cut signal that this method should not be used.